# Does a CPU clock frequency vary on-demand?

Tags: cpu, cpu-usage, cpu-architecture, cpu-speed

On my machine (not a personal computer), I have 4 cores (2.4GHz) and I currently don't have any important process running. Right now, are all of my 4 cores running/vibrating at 2.4GHz or are some of them running slower or even are immobile?

Comment: Your question is not clear.  You don't have 24 processors.

Comment: So you couldn't edit his question to clarify? You know what he means.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Yes**

Your processor has a base clock or [Front Side Bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front-side_bus) speed, my i7 is ~100MHz, there is then a multiplier that can change based on the demand of the processor - this 2.6GHz processor can have a clock multiplier that goes up to 36 to give me a maximum clock speed of ~3.6GHz.

Because most of the time your machine is sitting idle, that multiplier will sit around 8x, meaning my machine is only running at 800MHz, it could change multiple times per second.

I dont know what processor you have, so I can not tell you what yours is doing, but *most* modern processors do this, including your cellphone, it is called [speed stepping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpeedStep) and is what your system does to save energy.

You can check out [CPU-Z by CPUID](http://www.cpuid.com/downloads/cpu-z/cpu-z_1.73-en.zip) to view the details of your system (windows).

Or if you are running linux on a system that has a `/proc` system, you can run `cat /proc/cpuinfo` to view the details about your processor. In this printout, and on the CPU page of CPU-Z you an view the max speed, the current speed, the multiplier, and the maximum multiplier.

Note that this multiplier applies to every one of your cores, so if your system were to have say 8 cores - all of them would all be running at the same frequency.

**Here is my system sitting idle**, notice it is running at about 800MHz with a multiplier of 8, the minimum for this processor.

[image: min load]

**Here is my system under moderate load**, running at 3.4GHz with a multiplier of 34. (note the core voltage also increases)

[image: moderate load]

The bus speed of 100 MHz will be generated by a [PLL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-locked_loop) on board the motherboard - this is the master clock that is sent to each other logic component on the motherboard, i.e. pci, ram, usb controller, etc... This is the signal that is passed to the physical CPU through the socket.

The core speed, ~3.4GHz, is generated by a second PLL on the CPU itself, using the FSB as its source.

**Overclocking**

When people *overclock* their machines, this is usually just upping the FSB speed - which just makes everything run faster; the problem with everything running faster, is that it sucks more power - usually requiring a slight overvolting as well.

Where people start to experience issues is that when running at full power, firstly, the silicon gets extremely hot, and second, the high-er then rated voltages start saturating nearby transistors, mere microns apart on the silicon - potentially damaging the silicon itself, and interfering with other parts of the cpu.

**HLT**

After answering this question, I myself asked if there were any additional power saving techniques, to which the [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1121700/169705) was [the `HLT` instruction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HLT_(x86_instruction));

After the CPU has finished processing its workload, it will execute a halt, essentially disabling the core until the next interrupt is fired. In this state, the clock is still running at FSBxMlt., but the CPU core is doing no work, and is essentially drawing no power.

You can see the `HTL` instruction process in Windows Task Manager, it's name is *System Idle Process*; all unused CPU time will be spent executing `HLT`.[image: system idle process]

Comment: Thank you +1 I have a 6-Core Intel Xeon (on Mac) but there's no need to address that in your answer.

Comment: Note that a system that's **really** idle shuts down the CPU clock entirely. (sleep states, C2 and higher). Modern CPU's will also power down their caches if idle long enough (C3). What you're describing here are the power states used while in C0 (not asleep)

Comment: I am not so sure about all cores running at the same speed. I have frequently seen `/proc/cpuinfo` indicate that cores were running at different speeds.

Comment: Oh? Do you have any links that show this in action? I don't think I have ever seen different cores operating at different speeds, except in the `big.LITTLE` architecture of some ARM processors which are seldom used in personal computers.

Comment: Matt Clark, https://www.google.com/search?q=i7z&tbm=isch

Comment: @piec: Checked the first half-dozen images and they are all baloney, because fractional multiplers aren't possible.  Perhaps that program is doing some type of averaging (and if not simultaneous sampling across all cores, it may well show different averages for different cores, even if all are locked together).  However, it is true that cores don't have to use the same multiplier.

Comment: @Ben Voigt, user software can only do estimations and averages, frequencies change all the time without it knowing https://code.google.com/p/i7z/source/browse/trunk/i7z_Dual_Socket.c#343 https://code.google.com/p/i7z/source/browse/trunk/helper_functions.c#154

Comment: @piec: While it's true that a kernel driver is usually needed for reading the actual speed stored by hardware, that doesn't excuse code that fails to do it.  Anyway, code that is accessing MSRs should have knowledge of the actual multiplier, not merely estimates.